# why automatically converting to ISODate?

Tags: mongodb

On shell I tried on test db

```
post = {"title" : "My Blog Post", "content" : "Here's my blog post.", ... "date" : new Date()}
```

but when I tried to retrieve it using command

```
db.blog.find();
```

its giving me output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f13fdc4af1aaf90a686f8ae"), "title" : "My Blog Post", "content" : "Here's my blog post.", "date" : ISODate("2012-01-16T10:35:54.985Z") }
```

why its showing date as ISODate?? Can I not save date just what new Date() is return in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISODate is the shell's helper function to wrap javascript's Date constructor.  Calling `ISODate()` and `new Date()` should produce the exact same Date object, it will just be printed differently.

```
> var date = new Date(2012,01,16,10,35,54,985)
> var isodate = ISODate("2012-01-16T10:35:54.985Z")
> date.constructor == isodate.constructor
true

> date.constructor
function Date() {
    [native code]
}
> isodate.constructor
function Date() {
    [native code]
}
```

but:

```
> date.valueOf()
1329384954985
> isodate.valueOf()
1326710154985
>
```

however if you use the exact same millisecond to construct them then they are equal:

```
> date = new Date(isodate.valueOf())
> print(date)
Mon Jan 16 2012 11:35:54 GMT+0100 (CET)
> date.valueOf() == isodate.valueOf()
true
```

Comment: so new Date(2012,01,16,10,35,54,985) is equal to ISODate("2012-01-16T10:35:54.985Z")?

Comment: Not really, because Javascript Date is weird. First of all, you must use the "new" keyword in front of Date or it just returns a string. Secondly, Date uses 0-11 for months so you need to use 0 for month instead of 1 when using Date. However, ISODate is just a factory method for Date, so they could be used interchangeably if you use equivalent argument values.