# How to add Timestamp to Spring-Data-Mongo in Roo?

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, spring-roo

I have a Spring Roo project I am trying to create based on log4mongo-java appender and I want to get access to the data entries that looks like:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("4f16cd30b138685057c8ebcb"), 
"timestamp" : ISODate("2012-01-18T13:46:24.704Z"), 
"level" : "INFO", "thread" : "catalina-exec-8180-3", 
"message" : "method execution[execution(TerminationComponent.terminateCall(..))]", 
"loggerName" : 
    { "fullyQualifiedClassName" : "component_logger", 
    "package" : ["component_logger"], 
    "className" : "component_logger" 
    }, 
"properties" : { 
    "cookieId" : "EDE44DC03EB65D91657885A34C80595E" 
}, 
"fileName" : "LoggingAspect.java", 
"method" : "logForComponent", 
"lineNumber" : "81", "class" : { 
    "fullyQualifiedClassName" : "com.comcast.ivr.core.aspects.LoggingAspect", 
    "package" : ["com", "comcast", "ivr", "core", "aspects", "LoggingAspect"], 
    "className" : "LoggingAspect" 
}, 
"host" : { 
    "process" : "2220@pacdcivrqaapp01", 
    "name" : "pacdcivrqaapp01", 
    "ip" : "24.40.31.85" 
}, 
"applicationName" : "D2", 
"eventType" : "Development" 
}
```

The timestamp looks like:

```
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-01-17T22:30:19.839Z")
```

How can I add a field in my Logging domain object to map this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the JavaScript `Date` (according to the [mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types#JavaTypes-Dates/Times), and as can be [demonstrated in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878814/why-automatically-converting-to-isodate/8878883#8878883)), so try with `java.util.Date`.